# Passing string with dash as parameter into Trollop

Tags: ruby, trollop

I have created pretty simple ruby script which parses parameters with Trollop (2.1.2). It works fine until I'm passing value starting with `-` as parameter. Example:

```
def main
  opts = Trollop::options do
    opt :id, 'Video Id', :type => String
    opt :title, 'Video Title', :type => String
  end

  if opts[:id].nil? 
    Trollop::die :id, 'please specify --id'
  end
```

and when I'm running it with

```
ruby my_script.rb --id '-WkM3Blu_O8'
```

it fails with error

```
Error: unknown argument '-W'.
Try --help for help.
```

So how I can handle this case?

Comment: A few things I'd try to debug this: What is the value of `opts[:id]`, inside your `main` function? (Or is that code never reached?) What happens if you use double quotes? Or, no space between `--id` and its parameter? Or, what if you add a backslash like: `'\-WkM3Blu_O8'`? Or, is it valid to add an equals sign like: `--id='-WkM3Blu_O8'`?

Comment: Trollop is assuming that anything starting with a hyphen is an option that it should process.  Maybe try preceding the hyphen with a backslash?: `'\-WkM3Blu_O8'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trollop's job is to parse command line options.  If you had an option defined as '-W', how would it differentiate between that option and an argument that happened to begin with '-W'?

So even if there were a Trollop option to ignore unknown options and let them pass through as arguments to your program, if you defined any options at all you would still have the problem when a string began with a hyphen followed by the defined option's letter.

One thing you could do would be to require users who want to begin an argument with a hyphen to precede it with a backslash.  That would succeed in hiding it from Trollop, but then before using it you would need to remove the backslash.  As long as backslash would never be a legitimate character in the id string this should be ok.

By the way you might want to add the `short` option:

```
require 'trollop'
opts = Trollop::options do
  opts = Trollop::options do
    opt :id,    'Video Id',    type: String, short: :i
    opt :title, 'Video Title', type: String, short: :t
  end
end

p opts
p ARGV
```

You could try running it like this, and then observing the result:

```
➜  stack_overflow git:(master) ✗   ./trollop.rb -i 3 '\-i1'
{:id=>"3", :title=>nil, :help=>false, :id_given=>true}
["\\-i1"]
```

Comment: Backslash works fine, I've hoped that there is a way without using of duct tape :(